# WCF: Detect when service contract has changed

Tags: wcf, silverlight, updates

I have a Silverlight application which connects to a WCF service. Sometimes the WCF service contract gets updated while a user is still using the application, in which case the user would need to refresh the page to download the latest Silverlight client.

I would like to detect when the service contract gets updated and display a prompt in the browser that says something to the effect of "New update detected - please refresh the page." I could use a try/catch block to handle CommunicationException, however that is a very generic exception that could happen for any number of reasons.

What is the best way to detect a contract mismatch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best is if you could have some operation GetServiceVersion() which the client can periodically poll (if you can push it to the client even better). If the server cannot "cooperate" then the client has to download the wsdl and see if it changed, try to avoid that.